# Applying Trapdoor Function directly to plaintext

Tags: trapdoor

Suppose we have a secure trapdoor function defined on (G, F, F^-1) where G is a randomized algorithm outputs a key pair (pk, sk). Why would this trapdoor function become insecure if we apply F directly to plaintext message?
E(pk,m) = c = F(pk, m)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "directly on plaintext"? Without a secure padding scheme or without hashing the input before encryption? Or something else?

Comment: It's just a very simple encryption where 
G() generate (pk, sk); F(pk, .) is a deterministic algorithm that defines a function X->Y ;F^-1(sk, .) defines a function Y -> X that inverts F(pk,.)

Comment: Yeah, I did understand that, but I don't know what you mean with the "apply F directly to the plaintext message" << What do you want to do instead? Hashing the message? Or applying a padding scheme like OAEP?

Comment: Instead of using a random hashing function to get k = H(x) where x is random and output ciphertext c = (F(pk,x), E(k,m)), the scheme above just simply outputs c= F(pk, m)

Comment: What does "secure" mean in this context? It can't be IND-CPA, because that does not work with a deterministic encryption function. It can't be in the context of signatures, because there you use $F^{-1}$ to generate the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trapdoor functions only provide one-wayness. This means, that if one uses a trapdoor function to encrypt this may leak large parts of the plaintext. Suppose I have a trapdoor function $F(pk,m)$ for say n-bit messages $m$. I can now define an adapted trapdoor function working on $2n$ bit messages as

$F'(pk,m_1||m_2) = m_1 || F(pk,m_2)$

This is still a secure trapdoor function but, leaks half of the bits of the "plaintext".

Answer (score 2):

An eavesdropper could easily test any candidate message to determine

whether or that candidate message was the plaintext message.

```
def test_candidate_message_(pk,c,candidate):
 if c == F(pk,candidate):
  return True
 else:
  return False
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example how an eavesdropper can break this scheme?

Comment: I just did that. $\;$

Comment: How would that change if the message was first hashed before using the trapdoor function?

Comment: @Nova : $\:$ The eavesdropper would first hash `candidate` before using the trapdoor function. $\hspace{.69 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yes, that's right, but that is exactly what hvuong91 did ask: Why does that become insecure if we don't do that? It would not change anything, because the attacker would still be able to try that. It's both insecure, and the question asks why not hashing is insecure while hashing is secure.

Comment: @Nova : $\:$ No, hvuong91 didn't say that hashing was the alternative. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Did I misunderstand his comment on the original question then? It looks like exactly that to me.

Comment: @Nova : $\;\;\;$ Perhaps, but in any case, I hadn't noticed that comment. $\:$ "Why does" what "become insecure if we don't do that"? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: hvuong91 asks why his/her mentioned scheme becomes insecure if we don't use a hash function - but it is already insecure, because your attack also works with a hashed input.

Comment: @Nova : $\;\;\;$ My "attack also works with a hashed input", however, I don't see why that makes the scheme mentioned in hvuong91's comment at 04:45:27Z insecure. $\:$ (Is "his/her mentioned scheme" different from that one?) $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22052/discussion-between-nova-and-ricky-demer).